# How to play Flash in WPF?

Tags: wpf, flash

I need to create a user control that will play an `.swf` file.

Is it possible to play Flash in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)?

Answer (score 2):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d1b962c7-8a47-4809-a6e7-43f1a800a6eb/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few choices. Unfortunately I've never tried it, but I'd like to point you in the right direction:

- The WebBrowser control (ShDocVw and all that fun) is an HTML-hosting surface, you might be able to dynamically generate and host HTML containing the standard Flash plugin.
- The Flash ActiveX control ~ it may be possible to host it right inside your

Hope this gets you started. You'll probably end up using Windows Forms interop. Feel free to edit with more useful links.